# Can I deduct IRA contributions and take the standard deduction?

Tags: united-states, taxes, ira, tax-deduction, roth-ira

If I have the standard deduction on my taxes (that is, I don't itemize), can I deduct IRA contributions? If so, would that be for Traditional or Roth IRAs?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, a contribution to a Traditional IRA is an [above-the-line deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Above-the-line_deduction) assuming you meet the requirements [here](http://www.irs.gov/Retirement-Plans/IRA-Deduction-Limits), so you don't have to itemize to receive it. You only get a deduction for a Traditional IRA; Roth IRAs are after-tax.

Comment: How would I set this up with my broker an employer? I'm confused at how to alter my payroll information to deduct directly into an IRA for a traditional IRA.

Comment: IRA is _Individual_ Retirement Account. It is totally separate from your employer. You go to a broker (online or in person) and tell them you want to set up a Traditional IRA, after making sure that is the correct choice for you instead of a Roth IRA. Then you contribute directly, not through payroll deductions.

Comment: Really? I thought Traditional IRA's came from your gross pay similar to 401k contributions? I know Roth are from after tax...now I'm confused. Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Traditional IRA contributions are pre-tax, but that doesn't mean it has to be deducted from your paycheck by your employer. You get the deduction in the form of either a larger return or smaller bill when you file your taxes.

Comment: Yep you contribute the money and the amount you contribute goes right on the 1040 (hadn't heard the term above-the-line deduction before but thats basically what it means), and it reduces your taxable income that way. +1

Comment: Goooootchaa. Alright thank you! That clears it up pretty decently. !! +1 :)

Comment: @BenNelson A check on Google suggests that a number of banks offering IRAs do allow direct deposits to be setup.  Presumably you'd do that the same way you'd add a second bank account to receive part of your pay even if the tax benefits only showed up when you got your refund the next year.